# Search not working properly javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, search, match

I tried all the methods to search for a word in a string, but no success at all.

```
var val = "CM-08 INFORMATION SYSTEM COMPONENT INVENTORYSC-13 CRYPTOGRAPHIC PROTECTION; Rajani, Prem";

$('#master_DefaultContent_rts_ts5757_t').find('li').each(function () {

    var status = $(this).hasClass("hidden");

    if (status == false) {
        var tab = String($(this).text()).toUpperCase;
        var found = val.toString().search(tab);
        alert(found);
        alert(val.indexOf(tab));
                        alert( $.inArray(val,tab) )

        if (tab.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
            alert("test");
        }
    }

});
```

In above code val is CRYPTOGRAPHIC PROTECTION. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `.toUpperCase` should be `.toUpperCase()`

Comment: After that, your code can be shortened up a bit by improving the selector and removing `String(..)` -- http://jsfiddle.net/9N9Fb/